# Apache Shiro keeps redirecting to login page

Tags: web, shiro, login-control

I am having some troubles with Apache Shiro when I put the right user and password in the login page. It keeps redirecting me to the same page every time.

Here I have my project structure.

[image: UNASIS Tree Project Structure]

Now my Shiro ini file content

```
[main]
# specify login page
authc.loginUrl = /admin/login.jsp
authc.successUrl  = /admin/administracion.jsp

[users]
admin  = admin
guest = 12345

[urls]
/admin/login.jsp = authc
/admin/** = authc
```

Now, the login html form

```
<form class="formulario" name="loginform" action="" method="POST">
                <div id="descripcionPagina">
                    <h1>Login</h1><br>
                    Para ingresar al sistema <font color="red">identifíquese</font> como usuario del sistema.
                    <br>
                </div>
                <table id="tabla3" width="65%" cellpadding="8">
                    <tr id="fila">
                        <td align="right">
                            Identificación:&nbsp;
                        </td><td>
                            <input type="text" size="30"
                                   id="Lusuario" name="user">
                        </td>
                    </tr><tr id="fila">
                        <td align="right">
                            Clave:&nbsp;
                        </td><td>
                            <input type="password" size="30"
                                   id="Lpassword" name="password">
                        </td>
                    </tr><tr id="fila">
                        <td align="center" colspan="2">
                            <input type="submit" value="Ingresar">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </form>
```

The web.xml is fine and doesn't contain any web session parameters. Any help would be very appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried outputting the 'shiroLoginFailure' attribute of the request object?  Shiro populates a request attribute that key if authentication fails.

Comment: @Erlan you can try my answer

Comment: Thanks @Panchitoboy, my form uses "username" "password" fields. my problem was that I haven't added login page as authc. I needed to add url "/login.html = authc"

Answer (score 2):

I think that the problem is with the name of the fields:

Look at the source of the [FormAuthenticationFilter](https://github.com/apache/shiro/blob/d1a3d6c88a53678504a795dc4f38568cd2dff776/web/src/main/java/org/apache/shiro/web/filter/authc/FormAuthenticationFilter.java) (authc)

He need the fields : username and password.

You can change your html form

```
<input type="text" size="30" id="Lusuario" name="user">
```

to:

```
<input type="text" size="30" id="Lusuario" name="username">
```

Or you can add this in your shiro.ini

```
authc.usernameParam = user
```

Comment: Thank you. That was one of my problems. But actually, it was the order in which I was setting to each of the pages in the project. I published my shiro file to show how it is now, it's working.

Answer (score 0):

I think /admin/logging.jsp should be anon instead of authc